# CSS Image Replacement, but SHOW text when Images are disabled

Tags: css, image, replace, accessibility

I have recently put together a working navigation bar.

I'm pleased with it, but unfortunately it isn't accessible.

When images are OFF, I would like to show replacement text in its place.

Is this easy to achieve with my example: http://pastebin.com/hXth7FSK ?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Michael

Comment: Why don't you use real img <img> instead of background-image ? That way, you could benefit of the Alt properties (would display text if img are off).

Comment: I always presumed it was bad practice to use <img /> for the main navigation. I could be wrong.

Comment: you are. why would it be? that's why it has alt and titles that can be read by visually impaired people, aso.

Comment: @TigOldBitties Hold up on calling mcgarriers "wrong". It's generally considered bad practice to use images for main navigation because it's not semantic. Images have nothing to do with website navigation, they should be links.

Comment: Thanks, attack. "Semantic" was the word I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can absolutely position a span inside the element so that it covers the text as [this post from Dave Shea explains](http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/#shea):

```
<h3 id="header" title="Revised Image Replacement">
    <span></span>Revised Image Replacement
</h3>

/* css */
#header {
    width: 329px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    }
#header span {
    background: url(sample-opaque.gif) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

The only limitation is this will not work for partially transparent images.

Comment: With a little bit of jiggery-pokery, that did the trick: http://pastebin.com/0JvcXr0S Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Steve :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use background-images (I prefer background-images as well for navigations) you could absolutely position a blank image over it by adding this CSS: `position: relative; z-index: 100;` to all of the navigation elements with background images and then putting this in them:

```
<img src="pixel.gif" alt="Text to display when images are off" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 50;" />
```

Then, when the images are off, the alt text of the blank image will show. This image will be under the element, but when images are off, you will be able to see the image's alt text. Also, this will work for partially transparent background images.

You can use [this pixel.gif image](http://www.loremipsum.net/pixelgif/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now this is a very interesting theory. Can you show me how I would use it in the context of my HTML? Thanks for your reply. I think we've cracked it :)

Comment: @mcgarriers All you would have to do is add the `<img>` code above inside each of your menu elements, and make sure to add that CSS to the menu elements, inline CSS or inside the rest of your CSS. I tried doing it in jsFiddle, but for some reason when I added your menu CSS it made everything  hidden. I will keep trying and send you the URL to it when I'm done.

Comment: Coolness, Nathan. I managed to get a working solution from steve's above. But if you've got time, it'd be cool to see where this goes. Thanks again sir.